# Match values of columns of two files and join all matching lines in a new file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, compare

I've got two files and first look like this:

```
dif-1-2-3-4.com.log 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com.log 1 1 2
dif-1-2-3-5.com.log 2 1 1
dif-1-2-3-6.com.log 1 1 3
dif-1-2-3-6.com.log 3 1 1
dif-1-2-4-5.com.log 1 2 1
dif-1-2-4-6.com.log 1 2 2
dif-1-2-4-6.com.log 2 2 1
dif-1-2-5-6.com.log 1 3 1
dif-1-3-4-6.com.log 2 1 2
```

Second file look like this:

```
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1
dif-2-3-4-5.com 1 1 1
dif-3-4-5-6.com 1 1 1
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2
dif-2-3-4-6.com 1 1 2
dif-1-2-3-6.com 1 1 3
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1
dif-2-3-5-6.com 1 2 1
dif-1-2-4-6.com 1 2 2
dif-1-2-5-6.com 1 3 1
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1
dif-2-4-5-6.com 2 1 1
dif-1-3-4-6.com 2 1 2
dif-1-3-5-6.com 2 2 1
dif-1-4-5-6.com 3 1 1
```

I want this:

```
dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-2-3-4-5.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-3-4-5-6.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-2-3-4-6.com 1 1 2 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-1-2-3-6.com 1 1 3 dif-1-2-3-6.com.log
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1 dif-1-2-4-5.com.log
dif-2-3-5-6.com 1 2 1 dif-1-2-4-5.com.log
dif-1-2-4-6.com 1 2 2 dif-1-2-4-6.com.log
dif-1-2-5-6.com 1 3 1 dif-1-2-5-6.com.log
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-2-4-5-6.com 2 1 1 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-1-3-4-6.com 2 1 2 dif-1-3-4-6.com.log
dif-1-3-5-6.com 2 2 1 dif-1-2-4-6.com.log
dif-1-4-5-6.com 3 1 1 dif-1-2-3-6.com.log
```

If values in second third and fourth column in second file matching with values in first file then I want print line from first file behind matching line in second file. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you try anything? Hint: `awk`

Comment: @anubhava I was trying `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2$3$4]=$5;next}{(a[$2$3$4])}' file1 file2`
but I am not sure what this schould do.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. In the future, please include your code in your Q so readers don't have to ask you for it. However, `++` that you have included sample data and expected output. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a composite key using `$2,$3,$4` and do it like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$3,$4]=$1; next} {print $0, a[$2,$3,$4]}' file1 file2

dif-1-2-3-4.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-2-3-4-5.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-3-4-5-6.com 1 1 1 dif-1-2-3-4.com.log
dif-1-2-3-5.com 1 1 2 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-2-3-4-6.com 1 1 2 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-1-2-3-6.com 1 1 3 dif-1-2-3-6.com.log
dif-1-2-4-5.com 1 2 1 dif-1-2-4-5.com.log
dif-2-3-5-6.com 1 2 1 dif-1-2-4-5.com.log
dif-1-2-4-6.com 1 2 2 dif-1-2-4-6.com.log
dif-1-2-5-6.com 1 3 1 dif-1-2-5-6.com.log
dif-1-3-4-5.com 2 1 1 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-2-4-5-6.com 2 1 1 dif-1-2-3-5.com.log
dif-1-3-4-6.com 2 1 2 dif-1-3-4-6.com.log
dif-1-3-5-6.com 2 2 1 dif-1-2-4-6.com.log
dif-1-4-5-6.com 3 1 1 dif-1-2-3-6.com.log
```